# postfix + dovecot server successfully by client mail app problem to add account to this server

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I need help to solve this problem.

I setup a postfix and dovecot server and have some problems with the mail client.

I can received the mail and reply from the postfix. Just cannot setup a mail client on my android mobile phone.

Below are the mail.log :

```
__________________________________
May  4 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<coffee>, method=PLAIN, rip=136.228.129.92, lip=159.223.68.93, mpid=45086, TLS, session=<UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>
May  4 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: Effective uid=1000, gid=1000, home=/home/coffee
May  4 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:~/Maildir
May  4 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: maildir++: root=/home/coffee/Maildir, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/home/coffee/Maildir, alt=
May  4 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Connection closed (No commands sent) in=0 out=388 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
----------------------------

Below are the message from status of dovecot :

May 04 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot[44982]: imap-login: Login: user=<coffee>, method=PLAIN, rip=136.228.129.92, lip=159.223.68.93, mpid=45086, TLS, session=<UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>
May 04 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot[44982]: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: Effective uid=1000, gid=1000, home=/home/coffee
May 04 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot[44982]: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:~/Maildir
May 04 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot[44982]: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Debug: maildir++: root=/home/coffee/Maildir, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/home/coffee/Maildir, alt=
May 04 11:23:08 xxxxx dovecot[44982]: imap(coffee)<45086><UhCI2S3eNuuI5IFc>: Connection closed (No commands sent) in=0 out=388 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0

___________________________________________________
```

and try to add a new account on my android phone, click mail client apps to login:

**checking outgoing server settings....**

then after a 1 or 2 sec, it return
**Unable to complete
Couldn't connect to server.**

my email is coffee at trade.asia.

I need your help badly.

Appreciated you look at my problem.  Thanks and regards,

Choong Leng

Comment: Don't use POP3. It's an obsolete protocol

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what happens when you try to configure your Android client. Do you get any error messages? How do you know it's not working? Are you using exactly the same settings as for your working client?

Comment: Looks to me as if the Mailbox simply is empty (`retr=0/0, del=0/3`). Try to use IMAP4 as roaima suggested, so that the messages stay on the server.

Comment: Setting up a functioning MTA is a rather complex issue. To make it work correctly, you need to setup an MX record in DNS for the domain in any case, pointing to your server. I guess (do not really know) that this is what the android phone looks for. Search  for `DNS MX record`. Then you need to do client authentication,  otherwise anybody can send mails through your MTA. Search `SASL` and `DOVECOT`on the postfix.org site. At last you need to make it secure, and add SSL/TLS. Also see the postfix page.

Comment: Thank you Gerhard for the advise. And Roaima, thanks, what you info you need for this issue, can email to me (coffee@tradx.asia) we can communicate with email as well.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. It was the `first_valid_UID` setting on the `dovecot`, the default is `first_valid_UID = 500`.

I change to `first_valid_UID = 10`. That solved the problem.

Comment: Why would that help?  According to your logs you user `coffee` is `uid=1000, gid=1000`.  Lowering `first_valid_UID = 500` to 10 is weakening your security by allowing people to login as system accounts instead of actual users.